# Laser showing up in image for motion-activated shots

Tags: triggers, motion, triggertrap

Below is a photo triggered by a Miops shutter control using laser activation:

[image: motion activation]

The camera is set to take a burst every time it is activated.

The problem is that the laser is showing up in the image (the red dots on the right). Is this an unavoidable consequence of laser triggering, or is there a way to set up the shot so the laser does not hit the imaging sensor?

Answer (score 3):

1) Find a laser that is not in the optical wavelengths (and won't register on the sensor), or

2) Consider aiming it from below/behind, so it is aimed somewhat (but not quite) at the camera through the same space, and so the area it illuminates is on the bottom of the wing, and reflections from it are away from the camera.

The latter may or may not be effective depending on wing transparency or refraction.